# setTimeout counter not working

Tags: javascript, settimeout

This setTimeout function only runs once and then stops. I get no errors so I have no idea why it's happening.

```
count = 100;

counter = setTimeout('timer()', 100);

$('#reset').click(function() {
    count = 100;
    counter = setTimeout('timer()', 100);
})

function timer() {
    if (count <= 0) {
        clearTimeout(counter);
        alert('done');
    }
    $('#counter').html(count);
    count -= 1;
}
```

I tried a few different formulations of the setTimeout function, including `setTimeout(timer(),100)` and `setTimeout(function() { timer() }, 100)`

Comment: counter = setTimeout(timer, 100);  is the preferred syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's what `setTimeout` does. It runs the code once.

You want to use the `setInterval` method to run the code repeatedly.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `setInterval()` which repeats a function call, not `setTimeout()`, which does it once.  Also, don't use `()` in function name reference.

```
var count = 100;

var counter = setInterval('timer', 100);

$('#reset').click(function() {
    count = 100;
    counter = setInterval('timer', 100);
})

function timer() {
    if (count <= 0) {
        clearInterval(counter);
        alert('done');
    }
    $('#counter').html(count);
    count -= 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` works correctly but it is not what you are looking for. try `setInterval` instead. `setInteval(function, delay)`

Answer (score 0):

[`setTimeout()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) - executes a function, **once**, after waiting a specified number of milliseconds.

You probably would like to go for [`setInterval()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) which executes a function, over and over again, at specified time intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve, and I don't understand the **$('#reset').click** (etc) constructs.  Are these JQuery?

However, why not use setInterval()?  And then clear the interval timer when your condition is met?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var count = 10;

function counter() {

    if ( count > 0 )
    {
        --count;
        var t2 = setTimeout( counter, 1000 );

        document.querySelector("#demo").innerHTML = count;
    }
    else
    {
        clearTimeout(t2);

        document.querySelector("#demo").innerHTML = "Done";
    }
}

var countdown_timeout = counter();
```

```html
<p>Count: <b><span id="demo"></span></b></p>
```